# Can't get the Airconsole quickstart instructions to work

Tags: airconsole

I've created a new game/ directory on my webhost, and created and copy/pasted to the controller and screen html files as instructed at http://developers.airconsole.com/#/getting_started, but the game just comes up as a blank screen when I test it at http://www.airconsole.com/simulator/#(myurl)/game/ (tried both with and without "simulator")
Any suggestions as to what might be causing the issue?
I can access both files in my web browser, and I've verified that the javascript is visible in the source of both, so it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue or problem with the content of the file.
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: It seems it's an issue with the version of airconsole.js that's included in the example. Changing "1.2.1" to "1.1" in the first script (in both files) fixes the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The getting started guide has been updated (including the examples) since you've posted this question.

Feel free to reply to this message if it still doesn't work for you.